# Is there a short translation for ‘worth a read’ or ‘worth a listen’?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Just looking for a nice succinct way to say these terms in German:

> *worth a read*

and

> *worth a listen* (video).

Can I say *lesenswert*?

*Sadly this isn’t in a dictionary as it is a phrase. Dictionaries give you individual words and I am searching English to German, not the other way around. I got *lesenswert* from Google Translate and you can’t trust these 100 % completely so I wanted to ask to verify.

Comment: Dictionary doesn't translate terms or sentences - unfair to down vote based on that.

Comment: Another note: A video will most likely be *worth a watch* ;)

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/dictQuery/m-vocab/ende/en.html?search=worth%20a%20read finds _It's worth reading_ with a translation. (cc @Jan)

Comment: Look up [worth](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=worth&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) and you'll find it. You also get "worth knowing/seeing/considering/living/mentioning/..."

Comment: Am I the only one who finds a subtle difference between "worth reading" and "worth a read" etc.? The latter form seems more casual to me, not quite as committed. "Give it a try" (the attempt doesn't cost much) vs."try it" (it's worth it). With "try" one can carry that into German ("einen Versuch wert" (but maybe not another) vs. "versuchenswert"); with "worth a read" I don't see how to distinguish it.

Comment: @Jan not always ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally every *worth a something* expression can be (more or less idiomatically) translated to *something-wert* in German. So a site, a video or a picture can be *sehenswert*, a book or an article can be *lesenswert* and a song can be *hörenswert*.

Unfortunately, it gets less idiomatic very quickly. So if something is *worth a try*, it would be a strech to say *versuchenswert* (but the word would nonetheless be understood). And attempting a *worth a buy* as *kaufenswert* is too far removed to actually work. The gist would still be understood, but you would get a ‘what the heck are you trying to say?’-look.

Comment: There are a few hits for _versuchenswert_ (even in books), though _einen Versuch wert_ is of course more idiomatic. _Kaufenswert_, on the other hand, is quite common.

Comment: @chirlu okay, erm ... give me a better example >_<'

Answer (score 7):

Yes, *lesenswert* and *sehenswert* are what your dictionary will suggest.

Comment: Sadly this isn't in a dictionary as it is a phrase. I got it from google translate and you can't trust these 100% completely so I wanted to ask to verify.

Comment: @shinninja Both words can be found in a German or a German to English dictionary.

Comment: 'worth a read' cannot. 'worth' and 'read' yes, but not 'worth a read'. I didn't know about Leo and use a print dictionary ;)

Comment: @shinninja, since you had already found it, you could have looked up [lesenswert in a dictionary](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lesenswert).

Comment: @shinninja: Good paper dictionaries list phrases, too.

Comment: @CarstenS I don't have a German to English dictionary. Just a basic English to German one. But Leo is a great resource - will be using that in future :)

Comment: For a place would you also say "sehenswert"?

Answer (score 1):

dict.cc is a great resource (not sure if you tried it, but just in case).

This is what I pulled from that: http://www.dict.cc/?s=worth+a+try

Of course, that only helps if there is a distinct noun for what you're declaring as worth. I'm not sure if "Eine Lesung wert" or "Eine Anhoerung wert" sounds natural in German.

Comment: No, the _-ung_ versions do not sound natural at all. One could use _-en_ infinitives instead: _ein Lesen wert_, _ein Anhören wert_. However, that will still sound strange in many a situation.

Comment: Lesung und Anhörung bedeuten etwas ganz anderes als etwas zu lesen bzw anzuhören: eine Lesung gibt es in der Kirche (lecture), und eine Anhörung vor Gericht (official hearing). Wenn Du Lesung und Anhörung im Sinne der Frage verwendest, verdrehst Du die Bedeutung.